# Number of photons per unit time produced from Cherenkov radiation

Tags: radioactivity, cherenkov-radiation

I am trying to create cherenkov radiation with radioactive source, I understand how to calculate the number of photons per unit lengh per unit wavelengh produced in a cherenkov radiation using the Frank-Tamm formula as shown here:

https://thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com/tag/frank-tamm-formula/

My problem now is to understand how do I write an expression for the number of cherenkov photons per unit time. I assume this has to do with the intensity of my radioactive source (how many decays in a unit time), the cross section of the media (for example if my media is a tiny rod, I will place my source outside the rod).